# Flutter: weird effect on global top container when changing page in Android

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

This is the error. You can see on top container showing an ad that it displays a black rectangle when changing pages. This is not related to the ad, I face same thing with an empty container:

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/lO-fWDZHGyI

main:

```
 home: LandingPage(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, child) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: SafeArea(
                 child: Column(
                  children: [
                  Provider.of<Ads>(context, listen: false).showAds
                      ? Provider.of<Ads>(context).showBanner()
                      : Container(),
                  Expanded(child: child!),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
```

Ad:

```
showBanner() {
    if (adBanner == null) return Container();

    return SizedBox(
      width: adBanner!.size.width.toDouble(),
      height: adBanner!.size.height.toDouble(),
      child: AdWidget(ad: adBanner!),
    );
  }
```

This top container lives there in all pages. This is the app in case you want to test it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drodriguez.time_tap

I have removed completely the animation but it doesn't look right. I'd like to have the native one